# How can I hide the loading spinner when the HTTP call is finished?

Tags: html, angularjs, http, loading

I have a simple HTTP get call with angularJS

```
  $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'Dashboard/GetDashboard'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.dashboard = response.data;           
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Sometimes the performance is very low when the dashboard is loading and I want to use a loading spinner from font-awesome. This is my HTML code on the index.

```
<i ng-hide="?" class="fa fa-refresh icon-options"></i>
```

I know I have to use ng-hide for it but I don't know what expression I have to use.

When the HTTP call is finished I want to hide the loading spinner.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards

Comment: You can set a boolean variable to true when the HTTP call is initiated and in the then block you can set it to false.

Comment: Just hide it on success ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some boolean variable and put it before your call and on success make it `true` like below :
    Using `ng-hide`

```
    $scope.isSpinnerHidden = false;
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Dashboard/GetDashboard'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.dashboard = response.data;  
            $scope.isSpinnerHidden = true;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }); 

<i ng-hide="isSpinnerHidden" class="fa fa-refresh icon-options"></i>
```

OR

Use `ng-show` like below

```
$scope.isSpinnerHidden = true;
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Dashboard/GetDashboard'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.dashboard = response.data;  
            $scope.isSpinnerHidden = false;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }); 

<i ng-show="isSpinnerHidden" class="fa fa-refresh icon-options"></i>
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: it would be better to call `isSpinnerVisible` as `isSpinnerHidden`, since `ng-hide` is used (which will display on false)

Comment: yeah you are right variable name should be more clear

Comment: funny enough the second example with `isSpinnerVisible` was actually fine

Comment: yeah, i think both are fine, its actual the functionality not the variable name he need :D

Answer (score 1):

so here is the solution assign a scope variable

```
$scope.loading = false;
```

when you do server call make this value true like

```
$scope.loading = true;
```

and after your results come make it to `$scope.loading = false;`

and in HTML use

```
<i ng-if="loading" class="fa fa-refresh icon-options"></i>
```

so whenever loading is true this  tag will be visible.